# Should Zookeeper be used to report process status?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

In my case, Process P1 spawns P2, P3, P4 and many other processes. These child processes could be on other machines. They can be spawned using orchestration systems such as Kubernetes. After spawning the process, P1 wants to know the status of P2 and the other processes. Should ZooKeeper be used so that P2 can send a heartbeat and other status messages to P1? Is that one of the use cases for Zookeeper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case of single node, I guess not. The processes you spawned are all in a single machine. There is no need to use ZK (which is typically used to maintaining state or metadata for cluster)

You could use [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) (e.g., signal, socket) to check the child processes's status in parent process.

**Updated Here**

If the processes across machines, we could use ZK (use ephemeral and sequential nodes) to maintain group membership, which is a typical usage of ZK, and you could refer to the below link for more details.

By the way, we do not need to send heartbeat ourselves, when a client connects to ZK, a session is established (ZK client library would automatically send a heartbeat after the session has been idle for **session timeout / 3**).

[ZooKeeper: Wait-free coordination for Internet-scale systems, Section 2.4 Group Membership](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/atc10/tech/full_papers/Hunt.pdf)

and [Apache Curator Group Membership](https://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/group-member.html)

Comment: Added that : These child processes could be on other machines. They can be spawned using orchestration systems such as Kubernetes.